# Where can I find the "waving person" icon from Google's Material Design Icon set?

Tags: icons, material-design, google-materials-design

This icon is beautiful and would be useful to us, but I can't find it in their icon set.

It's referenced in two places in their documentation:

1. https://material.google.com/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons (in "Gestures" section)
2. https://material.google.com/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons (in "Human Icon Rules")

[image: waving person]

Does anybody know where I can find the vector for this, or has anyone happened to recreate it? :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a specific resource rather than asking an UX question

Comment: Inkscape SVG vector file [http://www.thinkui.co.uk/examples/waving.svg](http://www.thinkui.co.uk/examples/waving.svg) is a close match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that those icons are only used for demonstration purposes, the current production icon set is here :

[Material Icons](https://material.io/icons/)

From their [changelog](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/releases) on their github repo they seem to just have added more over time instead of replacing them.

But you could use that image as a blueprint to make a new one, or even submit it to the repo.

Comment: Sounds like the answer is as you say. Roger's link is a quality icon though.